# Using session with jaxon php

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

Im trying to persist a value inside my JAXON controller using laravel.

```
session(['category'=>$category_id]);
```

but when i retrive the value

```
session('category');
```

No value has been saved.

I was monitoring the session folder but nothing is changing the session store file.

This only happend in the jaxon controller.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed.
https://github.com/jaxon-php/jaxon-laravel/issues/1

Since Laravel 5.2 using the web middleware is required to make sessions work, and the default route to Jaxon controller didn't.

Comment: Ty. Will try again